# Confluent kafka - java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: ... missing required field

Tags: hive, avro

i am using confluent-3.0.1, and want to try the Avro schema evolution, but it seems that there is some issue when i am trying the backward compatibility with hive.

first i declared this schema, queried hive and got the data.

```
public static final String USER_SCHEMA = "{" +
        " \"namespace\": \"example.avro\",\n" +
        " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
        " \"name\": \"user\",\n" +
        " \"fields\": [\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"now\", \"type\": \"long\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number\",  \"type\": \"int\"}" +
        " ]\n" +
        "}";
```

then i added new optional field to the schema, "a"

```
public static final String USER_SCHEMA = "{" +
        " \"namespace\": \"example.avro\",\n" +
        " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
        " \"name\": \"user\",\n" +
        " \"fields\": [\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"now\", \"type\": \"long\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number\",  \"type\": \"int\"}" +
        "     ,\n{\"name\": \"a\", \"type\": [\"null\",\"string\"], \"default\": null}" +
        " ]\n" +
        "}";
```

but when i queried hive, i got this exception:

" Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found example.avro.user, expecting example.avro.user, missing required field a"

i think it caused by the first rows that don't have the new field.
(in hadoop all the looks fine).

it seems to have problems only with null values, because if i am adding this field to the schema i do manage to query
hive after adding new field.

```
public static final String USER_SCHEMA = "{" +
        " \"namespace\": \"example.avro\",\n" +
        " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
        " \"name\": \"user\",\n" +
        " \"fields\": [\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"now\", \"type\": \"long\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number\",  \"type\": \"int\"}" +
        "     ,\n{\"name\": \"favorite_color\", \"type\": \"string\", \"default\": \"green\"}" +
        " ]\n" +
        "}";
```

do you have any idea what could be the problem ?

thanks !

Comment: What version of avro and hive are you using?

Comment: avro 1.8.1 (in my producer) 

avro 1.7.6 and hive 1.1.1  ( on the claudera docker, i'm using it for hadoop and hive )  

this is the claudera docker  https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html)

thanks!